# Where to keep the token from Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a website like: http://webapi.com (written with ASP.NET Web API), and another website like: http://consumer.com (written with ASP.NET MVC).
Consumer passed the username and password to this webapi and it gives me a token.

```
{
  "access_token": "XuGGwTfZ_XvapFtwsFO0-...",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 86399
}
```

My question is, where should I store this token in consumer app?
In consumer website I have an action like:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginUserViewModel data)
{
   var response = PostAsync<LoginUserResultViewModel>("http://webapi.com/token",
       new StringContent("grant_type=password"+ 
        "&username=" + data.Username + 
        "&password=" + data.Password, 
        Encoding.UTF8, 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

   HttpContext.Session[BLConstants._TOKEN_SESSION_NAME_] = response.Token;

   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(data.Username, createPersistentCookie: true);

    return View();
}
```

In another action in consumer like: HomeController->GetList that I need that token for sending to the webapi to get the list, but I don't have that HttpContext.Session[Constants._TOKEN_SESSION_NAME_], and it's null.

Is there any other place that I should store the token? Is it secure to store this token into session?

Comment: You could store the information in a cookie (preferable encrypted) or you can carry it around in the user HttpContext.Current.User with a custom Principle you create.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/80767/136870 and http://security.stackexchange.com/a/100799

Comment: Check if you are not setting "HttpContext.Session[BLConstants._TOKEN_SESSION_NAME_]" to "null" somewhere between call to second action method. It should be available in the second action method.